# Density function in phase space

Tags: statistical-mechanics, density, phase-space, volume

What does density function in phase space physically mean? How does it indicate,  the more familiar density that we are accustomed to ( an analogy may be), in phase space?

Answer (score 2):

It is a [**probability** density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function), not a density of something like matter or energy.

The probability density $f$ answers the question "how likely is it (what is the probability that) the microstate $\omega$ in one of the points in some set $A$":

$$P(\omega\in A) = \int_A f(p,q)dpdq$$

The most other famous example of probability density in physics is the squared modulus of the wave function $\psi$,  $|\psi(x)|^2$ being the probability density of finding the particle at point $x$. Another example is [Brownian motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_motion) of a single particle.

Answer (score 1):

If you integrate out the momentum variables, then you get the usual density as a function of just position. Let's say there are N particles each with mass $m$ so total mass $Nm$.

$$
\int d^3p d^3x \; \; \rho_{phase} (x,p) = Nm\\
\int d^3p \; \; \rho_{phase} (x,p) = \rho (x)\\
$$

So the phase space density is giving more refined information. Careful that the units are different. For example, $\rho$ has units mass per volume, but $\rho_{phase}$ has units like $kg/(m kg m/s)^3$